# get server name and port number of JSP page for HTTPS

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, spring-mvc, jstl

i need to make the URL for my form action but the form should be submitted under `https` currently the underlying system running on 9002 port for the HTTPS.I can not use the following option in my JSP page

```
<form:form action="${request.contextPath}/springSecurity/login"
method="post" commandName="loginForm" target="guestFrame">
```

since when in HTTP the context path is coming as HTTP and the system will throw an exception as form should be submitted by HTTPS.
i can not hard code the action URL as currently its under develoment as the host name is `localhost`, even the HTTPS port is configurable so its even can not be hard-coded.

Is there any way i can create the URL in my JSP using JSTL or any other way so as to i can submit the form under HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpServletRequest.getServerName()` will give the server name. But, there is no way to get the `https` port. You should be using the default `443` if you want to fix it in your approach.

But the good solution is to use the `Security Transport Guarantee` for the login url, such that the server will automatically redirect the `springSecurity/login` page to `https`.

**Add this entry to the `web.xml` which will automatically redirect the `springSecurity/login` to `https`.**

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>secure</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/springSecurity/login</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```